# Unable to display UNICODE in UITABLEVIew Iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
NSString *cellValue = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
```

listOfItems is an `NSMutableArray` which gets values from sqlite table in the format "\u0C35\u0c36\u0C37".

When `UITABLEVIEW` is loaded I am seeing again same values "\u0C35\u0c36\u0C37" in the table.

But if I assign `cell.textLabel.text = @"\u0C35\u0c36\u0C37"`, I am getting the unicode equivalent characters(I mean international characters).

Answer (score 0):

You should load your SQLite rows using the [NSString stringWithUTF8String: ]  or  [NSString stringWithCString:  encoding: ]

Comment: You mean when inserting values into SQlite? table? or NSString *cellValue = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

Comment: a mean when loading rows from your database into listOfItems

Comment: listOfItems = dbMgr.getData;                                    getData(){ NSString *selectSQL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select * from main;"];NSMutableArray* users = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
          
 FMResultSet *rs = [self.db executeQuery:selectSQL];
      
 NSLog(@"%@",selectSQL);
   while ([rs next]) {  

 NSString *password = [rs stringForColumnIndex:1];
 
 const char *utfString = [password UTF8String];
    NSLog(@"%s",utfString);   
 NSString *pwd = [NSString stringWithCString:utfString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
 
 [users addObject:pwd];

Comment: const char *utfString = [password UTF8String]; NSLog(@"%s",utfString); NSString *pwd = [NSString stringWithCString:utfString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; [users addObject:pwd];  -  why are you converting from NSString to char and then again to NSString?

Comment: @user597677 ... please don't edit commentary into a proposed edit ... it makes my life very confusing ... http://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/1414

Comment: If i give NSString to cell.textLabel.text I am getting unicode characters ie \u0C35 so i tried to convert it to char * and assign it to label text but it is throwing error..so tried different options but ending up short.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831935/how-to-convert-unicode-strings-u00e2-etc-into-nsstring-for-display

Comment: Thanks Max ..Any suggestions or 3rd party tools?