# Issue in String return from NSdictionary in Iphone

Tags: iphone

i got a string from the json parsing is given below

```
{"categories":[{"Id":"4","name":"hm\u00c3\u0080\u00c2\u00afI\u00c3\u0084"},{"Id":"257","name":"Atkmkntbj\u00c2\u00b3"},{"Id":"258","name":"kv]ncnNz\u00c3\u00b0"},{"Id":"259","name":"tlm\u00c2\u00abv Uo\u00c3\u00b0kv"},{"Id":"260","name":"hnt\\mZw"},{"Id":"265","name":"kvs]jy\u00c3\u00b0kv"},{"Id":"273","name":"tImfwkv"},{"Id":"278","name":"Fgp\u00c2\u00afv"},{"Id":"285","name":"tNmtZym\u00c2\u00afcw"},{"Id":"290","name":"BiwkI\u00c3\u0084"},{"Id":"291","name":"\u00c2\u00a2mknss^Uvkv"}]}
```

I uses the code

```
list = [(NSDictionary*)[responstring JSONValue] objectForKey:@"categories"];

NSLog(@"%@\n\n",list);

for (int i = 0; i<[list count]; i++)

{

    NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *) [list objectAtIndex:i];

    [array_maincategory addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"name"]];

    NSLog(@"value = %@",[array_maincategory objectAtIndex:i]);

}
```

i get response like this

```
2012-11-21 09:29:01.784 BritishMalayali[412:fb03] value = hmÃ€Â¯IÃ„

2012-11-21 09:29:01.786 BritishMalayali[412:fb03] value = AtkmkntbjÂ³

2012-11-21 09:29:01.787 BritishMalayali[412:fb03] value = kv]ncnNzÃ°

2012-11-21 09:29:01.789 BritishMalayali[412:fb03] value = tlmÂ«v/ UoÃ°kv

2012-11-21 09:29:01.790 BritishMalayali[412:fb03] value = hnt\mZw

2012-11-21 09:29:01.791 BritishMalayali[412:fb03] value = kvs]jyÃ°kv

2012-11-21 09:29:01.793 BritishMalayali[412:fb03] value = tImfwkv

2012-11-21 09:29:01.794 BritishMalayali[412:fb03] value = FgpÂ¯v

2012-11-21 09:29:01.797 BritishMalayali[412:fb03] value = BiwkIÃ„
```

in the above response some text is missing 
my required response is like this  hm\u00c3\u0080\u00c2\u00afI\u00c3\u0084
and got as hmÃ€Â¯IÃ

so please help to get the correct response

Comment: You're getting what you're supposed to get.  The `\uNNNN` strings are Unicode encodings of non-ASCII characters.  They get converted into Unicode characters when the JSON string is parsed.

Comment: i know that is there ay way to get the same string as response
here 
hm\u00c3\u0080\u00c2\u00afI\u00c3\u0084
the above value is a shows some malayalam word so i want to get it correctly.plse help me to get the correct code

Comment: You have the correct numerical codes.  To display them you need to use the correct font and the correct mapping from Unicode to font characters.  To convert back to escaped codes you need to convert to ASCII again.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue related to string Encoding.
You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441989/how-to-change-an-nsstrings-encoding) question for the solution.