# How to convert all \u**** string into the real readable NSString?

Tags: iphone, unicode, nsstring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert Unicode strings (\u00e2, etc) into NSString for display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831935/how-to-convert-unicode-strings-u00e2-etc-into-nsstring-for-display)

I am downloading web pages into a NSString.

After downloading, it turns out to be that many chars in some web pages look like these:

`**\u003c**div style\u003d\"float:left;padding-right:10px\"\u003e\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u003cdiv\u003e\u003ca title\u003d\"Click here to read Penn State NCAA Sanctions: Four-Year Bowl Ban, Vacated Wins, $60 Million Fine, Significant Scholarship Reductions\"`

I wish to use regex `<img[^>]*>` to parse all images out, but with these `\u****` thing, I can't do that.

Is there a way to pre-transforming all those `\u****` thing into readable chars like `<`?

Thanks

Comment: [Some possibilities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795702/how-to-convert-uxxxx-unicode-to-utf-8-using-console-tools-in-nix)

Comment: There are a hundred different formats that use `\u` escapes, find out which one you have and use a proper parser for it, not a regex hack. Best guess given no other information: JSON.