# Objective C, unescape unicode characters

Tags: cocoa, unicode, nsstring

Does anyone have better solution or ideas than

[Using Objective C/Cocoa to unescape unicode characters, ie \u1234](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099349/using-objective-c-cocoa-to-unescape-unicode-characters-ie-u1234)

for unescaping unicode characters in NSString?

Comment: @JensAyton, How is this a duplicate of a question which is mentioned in this question?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using JSON, no.

[Using Objective C/Cocoa to unescape unicode characters, ie \u1234](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099349)