# -[__NSArrayI stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im trying to clean up a json stream and get the error listed above

```
NSString *traveladvice = [json valueForKeyPath:@"travel_advice_article.travel_advice_sections.body.markup"];
```

which gets me a stream with lots of javascript regular expressions like \U00a0 which I want to remove. Im using to regexlite to remove.

```
NSString *regexString = @"U00a0"; 
NSString *replacementString = @"";
NSString *travelparse1 = nil; 

travelparse1 = [travelAdvice stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:regexString     
withString:replacementString];
```

I understand the error but whats confusing me is that traveladvice is an NSString not an NSArray.

Comment: You do know that isn't a "javascript regular expression", but a UTF8 character representation, right?

Comment: Excuse me, UTF16. This question should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099349/using-objective-c-cocoa-to-unescape-unicode-characters-ie-u1234

Comment: thanks for that! the link was very useful indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json valueForPath might return an array, not a string.
stop in a debugger and do 'po traveladvice'
it will show you the actual data.

also, store the result type as 'id' and not NSString* to avoid confusion

Comment: Exactly the issue , traveladvice should be a NSArray thank you!