# unicode escapes in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, unicode

I have a string "Artîsté". I use json_encode from PHP on it and I get "Art\u00eest\u00e9".

How do I convert that to an NSString? I have tried many things and none of them work I always end up getting ArtÃ®stÃ©

```
For Example:
NSString stringWithUTF8String:"Art\u00c3\u00aest\u00c3\u00a9"];//ArtÃ®stÃ©
@"Art\u00c3\u00aest\u00c3\u00a9"; //ArtÃ®stÃ©
```

Comment: But do you need them as literals or dynamically? Because literals can contain unescaped UTF without any kind of problem on OSX.

Comment: Dynamically. I make an NSURLConnection and the results that come back  are the results of json_encode("Artîsté") which is "Art\u00c3\u00aest\u00c3\u00a9"

Comment: Use a general-purpose JSON parser to decode JSON data including strings. NSStringEncodingNonLossyASCII is very similar to JSON string literal syntax but not 100% the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `CFStringCreateFromExternalRepresentation` with the `kCFStringEncodingNonLossyASCII` encoding to parse the `\uXXXX` escape sequences.  Check out my answer here:

[Converting escaped UTF8 characters back to their original form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860867/converting-escaped-utf8-characters-back-to-their-original-form-in-ios-objective/7861345#7861345)

Comment: Good info thanks. I'm still getting the wrong info ArtÃ®sty©. I'm going to assume something is wrong on the php json_encode side since echo json_decode(json_encode("Artîsté")); gives me ArtÃ®sty© as well. Thanks.

Comment: `"Art\u00eest\u00e9"` is correct JSON or Java string literal for `Artîsté`; `"Art\u00c3\u00aest\u00c3\u00a9"` isn't. You might also have a problem displaying the final results?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your input string:

```
"Art\u00c3\u00aest\u00c3\u00a9"
```

does in fact literally mean "ArtÃ®stÃ©". \u00c3 is 'Ã',  \u00ae is '®', and \u00a9 is '©'.

Whatever is producing your input string is receiving UTF-8 input but expecting something else (e.g., cp1252, ISO-8859-1, or ISO-8859-15)