# XCode - convert as fly UTF8 character such as \u00e8

Tags: iphone, objective-c, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have an `NSString` that contains a string with UTF8 characters such as:
**"test \u00e8"** <- note that having a string containing this is different from having:

```
NSString *a = @"test \u00e8";
```

It's instead equal to have a string such as:

```
NSString *a = @"test \ \ u00e8"; //note the double \\ for escape...
```

So.. Obviously with `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:...]` I can't obtain the desired string that is: **"test è"**.

Is there a way to convert my string and make readable utf8 characters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting escaped UTF8 characters back to their original form in iOS/Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860867/converting-escaped-utf8-characters-back-to-their-original-form-in-ios-objective)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have to write something yourself, on the grounds that `\uabcd` is normally parsed by the compiler at compile time, rather than by `NSString`. Luckily I don't think it's that difficult.

```
NSString *fragments = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\u"];

if([fragments count])
{
    NSObjectEnumerator *stringEnumerator = [fragments objectEnumerator];
    NSMutableString *decodedString = 
                  [[[stringEnumerator nextObject] mutableCopy] autorelease];

    NSString *nextFragment;
    while(nextFragment = [stringEnumerator nextObject])
    {
         if([nextFragment length] >= 4)
         {
              unichar decodedCharacter = 0;

              for(int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
              {
                  unichar hexValue = [nextFragment characterAtIndex:c];

                  if(hexValue >= 'a')
                      hexValue = 0xa + (hexValue - 'a');
                  else
                      hexValue = hexValue - '0';

                  decodedCharacter = (decodedCharacter << 4) + hexValue;
              }

              [decodedString appendFormat:@"%C", decodedCharacter];
              [decodedString appendString:[nextFragment substringFromIndex:4]];
         }
         else
         {
              // there seems to be a parsing error; maybe just append
              // next fragment?
         }
    }

    NSLog(@"decoded string is %@", decodedString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Awesome! It worked.
There was some little syntax error so this is the correct code:

```
NSArray *fragments = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"\\u"];
if([fragments count])
{
    NSEnumerator *stringEnumerator = [fragments objectEnumerator];
    NSMutableString *decodedString =
    [[stringEnumerator nextObject] mutableCopy];

    NSString *nextFragment;
    while(nextFragment = [stringEnumerator nextObject])
    {
        if([nextFragment length] >= 4)
        {
            unichar decodedCharacter = 0;

            for(int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
            {
                unichar hexValue = [nextFragment characterAtIndex:c];

                if(hexValue >= 'a')
                    hexValue = 0xa + (hexValue - 'a');
                else
                    hexValue = hexValue - '0';

                decodedCharacter = (decodedCharacter << 4) + hexValue;
            }

            [decodedString appendFormat:@"%C", decodedCharacter];
            [decodedString appendString:[nextFragment substringFromIndex:4]];
        }
        else
        {
            // there seems to be a parsing error; maybe just append
            // next fragment?
        }
    }
    return decodedString;
}
return str;
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can do this in just one line: `return [NSString stringWithCString:[str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];`