# AFJSONRequestOperation crashing with "data parameter is nil" NSJSONSerialization error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I previously asked a similar question on this but didn't get much help and have now looked into it further and still can't see why I have a problem.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/all/json/sitelist?res=daily&key=<MY API KEY>"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Success");
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Fail");
}];
[operation start];
```

This fails with the following

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
```

I believe the problem is due to the JSON type returned as `ISO-8859-1`, I managed to get this working with `NSJSONSerialization` by encoding the retuned string to `NSUTF8StringEncoding`

Example...

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:kMetOfficeAllSites encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding error:&error];
NSData *metOfficeData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:metOfficeData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
if (error) {
    //Error handling
} else {
    //use JSON
```

So I looked at `responseJSON` in `AFJSONRequestOperation.m`

```
- (id)responseJSON {
[self.lock lock];
if (!_responseJSON && [self.responseData length] > 0 && [self isFinished] && !self.JSONError) {
    NSError *error = nil;

    // Workaround for behavior of Rails to return a single space for `head :ok` (a workaround for a bug in Safari), which is not interpreted as valid input by NSJSONSerialization.
    // See https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1742
    if ([self.responseData length] == 0 || [self.responseString isEqualToString:@" "]) {
        self.responseJSON = nil;
    } else {
        // Workaround for a bug in NSJSONSerialization when Unicode character escape codes are used instead of the actual character
        // See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12843465/157142
        NSData *JSONData = [self.responseString dataUsingEncoding:self.responseStringEncoding];
        self.responseJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:self.JSONReadingOptions error:&error];
    }

    self.JSONError = error;
}
[self.lock unlock];

return _responseJSON;
}
```

The code is crashing in the `else` statement, however this seems to be doing what I was doing previously when using `NSJSONSerialization` directly and re-encoding the responseString.

I even hardcoded `dataUsingEncoding` to `NSUTF8StringEncoding` but it still crashes and I don't understand why?

Note: The above works fine with other JSON feeds, also from other feeds on

http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/ but

[http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/all/json/sitelist?res=daily&key=](http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/all/json/sitelist?res=daily&key=%3CMy%20Key%3E)

includes the place name `Sóil Chaorainn` which causes the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the text encoding of the response is wrong. There are characters that can't be encoded using `ISO-8859-1`. This is why the `responseString` method (see AFURLConnectionOperation.m) returns nil and the JSON serialization fails.

To solve the issue you could subclass `AFJSONRequestOperation` and override `responseStringEncoding` in this way to enforce UTF-8 encoding:

```
- (NSStringEncoding)responseStringEncoding {
    [self.lock lock];
    if (!_responseStringEncoding && self.response) {
        self.responseStringEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding;
    }
    [self.lock unlock];

    return _responseStringEncoding;
}
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as when I tried NSData *JSONData = [self.responseString dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: No, because the responseString method uses responseStringEncoding  itself and thus would be nil.