# NSJSONSerialization returns EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, json, exc-bad-access, nsjsonserialization

I am parsing a JSON file created by a PHP-Script using NSJSONSerialization.
When I clear the code (Product - clear) it works perfectly. But when I stop the program and build it again without Product - clear, it will crash at this line with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
I use ARC.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:adresse]];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
if (response == nil) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Connection" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
else {
    if (![NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError]) {
        UIAlertView *jsonAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"JSON Parsingerror" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [jsonAlert show];
    }
    else {
        jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
```

Working around the problem caused by escaped unicode characters by adding this

```
NSString *escaped = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *name = [NSString
                   stringWithCString:[escaped cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                   encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSData *responseData = [name dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
responseData = [responseData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [responseData length]-1)];
```

and changing

```
jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
```

to

```
jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
```

results in a SIGABRT crash.

What am I doing wrong? It WORKS for the first time AFTER product clear but then crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS despite using ARC.

My JSON looks like that

```
[{"line":"ABC","date":"2013-10-02","description":"H\u00e4hnchenbrust mit Calvadosso\u00dfe (1,2,4,8)","art":"type1"},{"line":"DEF","date":"2013-10-02","description":"Frika‌​dellen \u0084Polpette\u0093 (Rind) mit Sardellen und Tomaten (8)","art":"type1"},{"line":"ABC","date":"2013-10-03","description":"Salatteller mit Gem\u00fcseschnitzel (4,2,8)","art":"type2"},{"line":"ABC","date":"2013-10-27","description":"Nudel-H‌​ackfleisch-Pfanne (Rind) mit Schafsk\u00e4se (2,4)","art":"type1"}]
```

Comment: There are [known bugs in NSJSONSerialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842481/nsjsonserialization-results-in-exc-bad-access) which can cause something like this. What does your JSON look like?

Comment: [{"line":"ABC","date":"2013-10-02","description":"H\u00e4hnchenbrust mit Calvadosso\u00dfe (1,2,4,8)","art":"type1"},{"line":"DEF","date":"2013-10-02","description":"Frikadellen \u0084Polpette\u0093 (Rind) mit Sardellen und Tomaten (8)","art":"type1"},{"line":"ABC","date":"2013-10-03","description":"Salatteller mit Gem\u00fcseschnitzel (4,2,8)","art":"type2"},{"line":"ABC","date":"2013-10-27","description":"Nudel-Hackfleisch-Pfanne (Rind) mit Schafsk\u00e4se (2,4)","art":"type1"}]

Comment: Put it in the question so that humans can read it.

Comment: Interesting! The NSURLConnection returns "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" I googled that but have not found the right answer so far. Product clear refers to xcode. "Product" in the top bar and then "clear"

Comment: It still crashes with the SIGABRT. When I remove the work-around for the escaped unicode characters it returns no error but crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the NSJSONSerialization line again

Comment: Hmm, I'm unable to reproduce your problem that necessitates the conversion of the unicode escape sequences, but if you want to "unescape" that string, I don't think your roundtrip to CString is the way to do it. I'd use `CFStringTransform`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace those escape sequences, you can use [`CFStringTransform`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001504-CH201-BCIGCACA):

```
NSMutableString *escaped = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
CFStringTransform((__bridge CFMutableStringRef)escaped, NULL, CFSTR("Any-Hex/Java"), YES);
NSData *unescapedData = [escaped dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I solved the problem. I used a separate class JSONParser.h /.m which was build again and again. I now just parse using the code directly from the parental class and it is working.