# How to decode Unicode escape sequence emojis encoded as \uXXXX?

Tags: python, json, instagram, emoji, python-unicode

I am trying to use python to sort through my downloaded Instagram data, the data is a json file, but emoji and other non-text characters are encoded in a way I do not understand, for example:

The json file will contain:
`\u00e2\u009c\u008c\u00f0\u009f\u0096\u00a4\u00f0\u009f\u008d\u0095\u00f0\u009f\u008e\u00b6\u00f0\u009f\u00a4\u00af`.
Which on the instagram app is displayed:
`✌`

Or json: `\u00e2\u0080\u0099`. Instagram: `'`(apostrophe)

I have tried to use `u"string"` and have found similar questions [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/423661-decoding-utf-8-type-emoji-codes-and-special-characters-from-facebook-data), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40597533/decode-string-with-emoji-characters-such-as-ud83d) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099349/using-objective-c-cocoa-to-unescape-unicode-characters-ie-u1234) but none are in python or provide any useful details to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')))
```

Comment: Hello, I am trying to write that text into a file, but I get the error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 12-14: character maps to <undefined>` . How can I fix this?

Comment: @HaykPetrosyan Does this answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters

Comment: Kinda, I just found later that the encoding of Instagram and Twitter texts are in latin-1 or something. So we must first decode from that then encode to utf-8 and do whatever.

Comment: @Ani +1 for this. Can you share the source or how you found it?

Answer (score -3):

if you are on windows press win + .
you will get a prompt with emojis
then do
`print("")`
output: