# iOS - XML to NSString conversion

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, nsxmlparser, nsstringencoding

I'm using `NSXMLParser` for parsing XML to my app and having a problem with the encoding type.  For example, here is one of the feeds coming in.  It looks similar to this"

```
\U2026Some random text from the xml feed\U2026
```

I am currently using the encoding type:

```
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Which encoding type am I suppose to use for converting \U2026 into a ellipse (...) ??

Comment: I thought \U2026 was "..." in unicode.  Also known as an Ellipsis.

Comment: My bad, you are correct that one is ellipse. However I do have some quotations also.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is you're screwed. They are using a non-standard encoding for XML, but what if they really want the literal `\U2026`? Let's say you add a decoder to handle all `\UXXXX` and `\uXXXX` encodings. What happens when another feed want the data to be the literal `\U2026`?

You're first choice and best bet is to get this feed fixed. If they need to encode data, they need to use proper HTML entities or numeric references.

As a fallback, I would isolate the decoder away from the XML parser. Don't create a non-conforming XML parser just because your getting non-conforming data. Have a post processor that would only be run on the offending feed.

---

If you must have a decoder, then there is more bad news. There is no built in decoder, you will need to find a category online or write one up yourself.

---

After some poking around, I think [Using Objective C/Cocoa to unescape unicode characters, ie \u1234](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099349/using-objective-c-cocoa-to-unescape-unicode-characters-ie-u1234) may work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, heres a snippet of code that should work for any unicode code-point:

```
NSString *stringByUnescapingUnicodeSymbols(NSString *input)
{
    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[input length]];

    // get the UTF8 string for this string...
    const char *UTF8Str = [input UTF8String];

    while (*UTF8Str) {
        if (*UTF8Str == '\\' && tolower(*(UTF8Str + 1)) == 'u')
        {
            // skip the next 2 chars '\' and 'u'
            UTF8Str += 2;

            // make sure we only read 4 chars
            char tmp[5] = { UTF8Str[0], UTF8Str[1], UTF8Str[2], UTF8Str[3], 0 };
            long unicode = strtol(tmp, NULL, 16); // remember that Unicode is base 16

            [output appendFormat:@"%C", unicode];

            // move on with the string (making sure we dont miss the end of the string
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                if (*UTF8Str == 0)
                    break;
                UTF8Str++;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if (*UTF8Str == 0)
                break;

            [output appendFormat:@"%c", *UTF8Str];
        }


        UTF8Str++;
    }

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simple replace literal '\U2026' on a quotation, then encode it with NSUTF8StringEncoding encodind to NSData

Comment: Nope. Not the way to do it, not extendable by any means. If I was to come along and add `\u2010`, for example, your code would break yet again, and you would need to re-compile with a new rule for that specific instance.