# UILabel text with unicode NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, unicode

This code shows correctly as `Ecole` with an accent on `E`:

```
NSString *test = @"\u00c9cole";
cell.detailTextLabel.text = test;
```

But when I get the string from my server sent as Json, I don't see `E` with an accent but rather the unicode `\u00c9`.

Code for getting Json string from server:

```
- (void) handleProfileDidDownload: (ASIHTTPRequest*) theRequest
{
    NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [str setString:[theRequest responseString]];
    [self preprocess:str]; //NSLog here shows  str has the unicode characters \u00c9

}

- (void) preprocess: (NSMutableString*) str 
    {
    [str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];
    [str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];
    [str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\\/" withString:@"/" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];

}
```

Now if I do,

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = str;
```

I don't get the accent for E rather \u00c9

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NSLog here shows  str has the unicode characters \u00c9

From that, you can know that the JSON you receive doesn't actually have the letter `É` inside but the escape sequence `\u00c9`. So, you need to somehow unescape this string:

```
CFMutableStringRef mutStr = (CFMutableStringRef)[str mutableCopy];
CFRange rng = { 0, [mutStr length] };
CFStringTransform(mutStr, &rng, CFSTR("Any-Hex/Java"), YES);
```

Then you can use `mutStr` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *test = @"\u00c9cole";
```

is converted by the complier to the accented E.

In your JSON, the string \u00c9cole is a literal backslash-u-zero-zero-c-nine.

You can get the same behavior by escaping the backslash.

```
NSString *test2 = @"\\u00c9cole";
```

This will give you the same bad result, \u00c9cole.

---

To correctly unescape the JSON string, see [Using Objective C/Cocoa to unescape unicode characters, ie \u1234](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099349/using-objective-c-cocoa-to-unescape-unicode-characters-ie-u1234).

I'm providing the link instead of an answer because there are three decent answers. You can choose the best one for your needs.