# UILabel Convert Unicode(Japanese) and display

Tags: unicode, uilabel

After hours of research I gave up.
I receive text data from a WebService. For some case, the text is inJapanese, and the WS returns its Unicoded version. For example: \U00e3\U0082\U008f
I know that this is a Japanese char.

I am trying to display this Unicode char or string inside a UILabel.
Since the simple setText method does'nt display the correct chars, I used this (copied) routine:

```
unichar unicodeValue = (unichar) strtol([[[p innerData] valueForKey:@"title"] UTF8String], NULL, 16);
char buffer[2];
int len = 1;
if (unicodeValue > 127) {
    buffer[0] = (unicodeValue >> 8) & (1 << 8) - 1;
    buffer[1] = unicodeValue & (1 << 8) - 1;
    len = 2;
} else {
    buffer[0] = unicodeValue;
}
    [[cell title] setText:[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ];
```

But no success: the UILabel is empty.
I know that one way could be convert the chars to hex and then from hex to String...is there a simpler way?

**SOLVED**

First you must be sure that your server is sending UTF8 and not UNICODE CODE POINTS. The only way I found is to json_encode strings which contain UNICODE chars.
Then, in iOS user unescaping following this link [Using Objective C/Cocoa to unescape unicode characters, ie \u1234](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099349/using-objective-c-cocoa-to-unescape-unicode-characters-ie-u1234)

Comment: The format `\U00e3\U0082\U008f` does not make sense to me, because if those represent raw UTF-8 bytes, the most significant byte is always `00`. Anyway, You need some way to convert `\U00e3\U0082\U008f` to the bytes `0xe3 0x82 0x8f`, and then decode those bytes as UTF-8.

Comment: The format is the output from a SBJSON parser, which in turn receives data from a WS written in php. The php code fetches data from a PostGreSql db, where some fields contain Japanese chars. For instance, I can see correctly those fields in phppgadmin....