# Turning escaped unicode char[] into NSString

Tags: ios, unicode, utf-8, nsstring

I have the following `char[] str = "\xe7a"`;

This is the result of having converted "ça" into unicode escaped with python `.encode('unicode-escape')`

When it gets to iOS I'm trying to convert it to "ça" again... but I can't find the right method to do it.

How can I convert \x escaped characters into their proper characters using iOS functions?

```
str = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:m.param5 length:STRING_PARAM_LENGTH encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] UTF8String];
```

doesn't work

```
str = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:m.param5 length:STRING_PARAM_LENGTH NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

doesn't work

```
str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:m.param5];
```

doesn't work as well

Any ideas?

Comment: You can think about CFStringTransform.

Check [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099349/using-objective-c-cocoa-to-unescape-unicode-characters-ie-u1234/11615076#11615076)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `\xe7` means the byte `0xe7`, the char array is encoded as Windows-1252/ISO-8859-1... so:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithCString:str encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```

If the contents are literally a backslash, `x`, `e`, and `7`, you need to turn that into the real implied byte value
before running the above code

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. How do I turn \xe7 into the real implied byte before?