# Xcode - UTF-8 String Encoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, utf-8

I have a strange problem encoding my `String`

For example:

```
NSString *str = @"\u0e09\u0e31\u0e19\u0e23\u0e31\u0e01\u0e04\u0e38\u0e13";
NSString *utf = [str stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog("utf: %@", utf);
```

This worked perfectly in log

```
utf: ฉันรักคุณ
```

But, when I try using my string that I parsed from JSON with the same string:

```
//str is string parse from JSON
NSString *str = [spaces stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"U" withString:@"u"];
NSLog("str: %@, str);
NSString *utf = [str stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog("utf: %@", utf);
```

This didn't work in log

```
str: \u0e09\u0e31\u0e19\u0e23\u0e31\u0e01\u0e04\u0e38\u0e13
utf: \u0e09\u0e31\u0e19\u0e23\u0e31\u0e01\u0e04\u0e38\u0e13
```

I have been finding the answer for hours but still have no clue

Any would be very much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `[str UTF8String];` before `NSString *utf = [str stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` ?

Comment: paste the code which creates the spaces

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi Yes I have. Didn't work :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string returned by JSON is actually different - it contains escaped backslashes (for each "\" you see when printing out the JSON string, what it actually contains is @"\").

In contrast, your manually created string already consists of "ฉันรักคุณ" from the beginning. You do not insert backslash characters - instead, @"\u0e09" (et. al.) is a single code point.

You could replace this line

```
NSString *utf = [str stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

with this line

```
NSString *utf = str;
```

and your example output would not change. The stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: refers to a different kind of escaping. [See here about percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

What you need to actually do, is parse the string for string representations of unicode code points. Here is a link to one potential solution: [Using Objective C/Cocoa to unescape unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099349/using-objective-c-cocoa-to-unescape-unicode-characters-ie-u1234/11615076#11615076). However, I would advise you to check out the JSON library you are using (if you are using one) - it's likely that they provide some way to handle this for you transparently. E.g. [JSONkit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) does.

Comment: Your second link worked perfectly! Thankyou! You just saved my life!

Comment: Hello I have & in my image url so if i pass with service server take it as new parameter so how to solve it. can you please tell. thank you @janis K