# iOS Unicode Encoding

Tags: ios, unicode, ios8

I am getting this kind of data ElbowWristHand_DeQuervian\U00e2\U0080\U0099s Tenosynovitis through a web service, But actually the content is "ElbowWristHand_DeQuervian's". I have followed all the methods mentioned in the following link:

[Using Objective C/Cocoa to unescape unicode characters, ie \u1234](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099349/using-objective-c-cocoa-to-unescape-unicode-characters-ie-u1234/11615076#11615076)

but still i am unable to convert the unicode characters to the proper string. Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While initializing string us unicode string encoding -

```
NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:recievedData usingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
```