# How to decode unicode text to HTML in Objective-C?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, unicode

I receive from my API a HTML code encoded with unicode style like this:

`\u003C\/span\u003E\u003Cspan xml=\u0022lang\u0022 style=\u0022border-collapse: collapse`

But I need to transform that into HTML code to show in a UIWebView. But I'm not be able to find a way similar to JavaScript `unescape()` to get the following NSString:

`</span><span xml="lang" style="border-collapse: collapse`

Comment: FYI - you mention `NSWebView` but tag the question iOS. Did you mean `UIWebView` or did you mean to tag this Cocoa?

Comment: Yes, UIWebView. Sorry it was a typo ;)

Comment: look here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099349/using-objective-c-cocoa-to-unescape-unicode-characters-ie-u1234/11615076#11615076

Comment: Looks like your API returns JSON. A standard JSON encoder should do the job.