# AFNetworking 3.0 Non English (Gujarati/Hindi) with Parameter not working

Tags: ios, afnetworking-3

Calling web-service using AFNetworking 3.0 with parameter value is non English character (Gujarati/Hindi).

My parameters are as follows:

1. TokenID
2. Application
3. UserID
4. addUpdateCustomerJson

Here my `addUpdateCustomerJson` parameter is JSON string so it will contains `NSMutableDictionary` and `NSMutableArray`.

```
Parameters: AddressDetails = "[\n  {\n    \"Pincode\" : \"400031\",\n    \"State\" : \"Maharashtra\",\n    \"Lattitude\" : 19.017614699999999,\n    \"AddressLine1\" : \"Victory Container Movies\",\n    \"Longitude\" : 72.856164399999997,\n    \"AddressLine2\" : \"Wadala\",\n    \"Country\" : \"India\",\n    \"Type\" : 1,\n    \"City\" : \"Mumbai\"\n  }\n]";
Application = SalesPro;
CompanyID = 1;
CustVendorDetails = "{\n  \"MobileNo\" : \"345345345334\",\n  \"ContactNo\" : \"\",\n  \"LandlineNo\" : \"\",\n  \"Tax_Type\" : \"VAT\",\n  \"CustomerCode\" : \"\",\n  \"DistributorID\" : 0,\n  \"CreatedBy\" : 18,\n  \"Name\" : \"\U0ab9\U0abf\U0ab0\",\n  \"EmailTo\" : \"\",\n  \"EmailID\" : \"\",\n  \"CompanyTypeID\" : 1,\n  \"Type\" : \"U\",\n  \"BirthDate\" : \"\",\n  \"PrimatyUserID\" : 18,\n  \"TaggedToID\" : 18,\n  \"SegmentID\" : 0,\n  \"CustomerClass\" : 1,\n  \"Description\" : \"\",\n  \"Key_Customer\" : false,\n  \"CompanyID\" : 1,\n  \"CustomerGSTNo\" : \"\",\n  \"OwnerID\" : 18,\n  \"ContactName\" : \"\"\n}";
TaggedUsersList = "[\n  {\n    \"TaggedUserID\" : 18\n  }\n]";
TokenID = BBF7B1E82D75939E9F29FCC59F0EF542;
UserID = 18;                                              
                                                          
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
NSLog(@"Customer Add/Edit JSON Object %@",[maindict description]);
[manager POST:kWSUrlAddCustomerVendor parameters:maindict constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {
    
} progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {

} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
    NSLog(@"%@",[dict description]);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
}];
```

Response:

```
data =     {
    AddressList =         (
                    {
            AddressID = 2056;
        }
    );
    CompanyID = 1;
    MobileNo = 345345345334;
    Name = "\U00e0\U00aa\U00b9\U00e0\U00aa\U00bf\U00e0\U00aa\U00b0";
    TaggedToIDList =         (
                    {
            ID = 4866;
        }
    );
    isActive = 1;
};
message = "Customer Created successfully";
status = Success;
```

Problem is in 'Name' field

it is in UTF encoding form

Comment: post proper detail like your try, error etc

Comment: discuss with server guy !!!

Comment: @SachinVsSachin already works for PHP so cant change from server

Comment: iOS UTF8Encoding generate issues like unicode with capital 'U' but unicode have small 'u'. [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099349/using-objective-c-cocoa-to-unescape-unicode-characters-ie-u1234?noredirect=1&lq=1